# Problems with jquery in ie9 ( .slidedown(), .hide() )

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, slidedown

I am trying to get a hidden div to .slideDown()/.slideUp() after the link above it is clicked. The div is has display property 'hidden'. It works completely fine in every browser but IE9. When i click my link in IE9 nothing happens, meaning the hidden div is not shown. But if I set the display property of the div as 'visible' it toggles very well. I tried .show()/.hide() and also .toggle() but i get the same results. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is my HTML code

```
<span class="toggle">
<li id="toggler">
    <a id="atoggler1" href="#">
        '.$info['category'].'
    </a></li></span>
<div class="hiddenDiv">
<p>
    $info['description']
</p>
.....
.....
 </div>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
.hiddenDiv{
    display: none;
 }
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".toggle").click(function () {

    // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
    if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown("fast"); // slide it down
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).next().slideUp("fast"); // hide it
        return false;
      }
  });
});
```

Also just for the record my HTML code is wrapped around php code. I did not include that for clarity purposes.

How can this problem be fixed? Or what are my alternatives??

Comment: Open the console (F12) and go to the Script console to see if any errors are happening(you'll have to reload the page)

Comment: your markup is incorrect.please modify it.

Comment: Invalid html will give you inconsistent results across different browsers.

Comment: `li` elements can only be contained in `ul`, `ol`, and `menu`elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/li

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next()` from

```
<span class="toggle">
```

is

```
<li id="toggler">
```

and not what you are trying to show which is

```
<div class="hiddenDiv">
```

according to your markup. If you use

```
$('#toggler').find('.hiddenDiv')
```

instead that should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

After fixing a missing close div in your HTML and modifying the code to target the right div, this is working fine for me in IE9:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".toggle").next().slideToggle("fast");
        return(false);
    });

});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d3TX9/

1. Your HTML in your question didn't have a closing `</div>` for the hiddenDiv
2. I made sure that no matter where the click happens, it will do `.next()` from the `.toggle` object.
3. I switched to `slideToggle()` for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it was not working if my link tag to my CSS file was inside the HTML tags. But if I left them outside it messed with my styling. After doing a lot of research I found there is a bug in either jQuery or IE9. When i ran my console i was getting an invalid call error when i clicked the link. This error was in my jQuery code at this particular line. The call was `this.appendChild( elem );` but to fix it i had to change it to `this.parentNodeappendChild( elem );` and it fixed it.

So in case if in the future anyone else has this problem here's how to fix it:

1. Depending on your jQuery version check for the line with error by running console
2. Go to that line and change `this.appendChild( elem );` to `this.parentNode.appendChild( elem );`